# Calculating p-value when tcalc, and df are given. Please help.

Tags: statistics

In a **two-tailed** t-test for means equality with **df= 22, tcalc=3.511, and .001 < p<.01**. How to calcultate exact p-value?

There was no table or anything else attached to this problem, and I can't find any examples in the book that would explain how to solve it when only this information is given. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use R or something similar as in

```
> 2 * pt(abs(3.511), df=22, lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 0.001971369
```

Comment: Could you please explain it?

Comment: Two-tailed (so double) the probability of being more extreme (so above) $3.511$ if there are $22$ degrees of freedom